# Eclipse don't read source

Tags: java, eclipse, text, editor

Faced with an unusual problem when Eclipce simply does not open the code, all objects in the outline available, the program starts.
Changing Workspace, Open with Java Editor, Text Editor, change the location does not help.
 I can't attach the image. 
UPD
It worked fine for a week, do not install. Any project can not see.
http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/error.1355781465.jpg

Comment: You will have to be more specific than 'does not open the code'. Perhaps upload an image to an external site (www.imgur.com) if you can't attach any?

Comment: It will be very hard for us to assist you unless you clarify.

Comment: That is Eclipse Juno, right? If you don't mind losing your workspace layout settings, you can try to rename or delete `.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi` in your affected Eclipse workspace. Close Eclipse before doing that, then restart.

Comment: Don't work . I have Run project on another pc, all right.
Any version Eclipce create this error.

Comment: Is it only a problem with .java files?  Does anything happen when you click and drag in the empty space?  Have you double-checked your Colors and Font preferences?

Comment: maybe, i don't used  other file, Nothing , only very big cursor,like 82. Colors is default

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try with a brand new workspace folder?

And what's in the Error view (Shift+Alt+Q then L), a screenshot would be helpful there.

Comment: New workspace also not help. Error view is empty, i can run project  and it's work fine.